# When will a deleted answer be removed completely?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, privacy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are deleted answers automatically removed, or is that done by a user with access to moderation tools?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62035/are-deleted-answers-automatically-removed-or-is-that-done-by-a-user-with-access)

I have deleted one of my answers a week ago, it is still being kept under that question.

Even though only myself and high reputed trusted users can see it, this situation (keeping deleted user entries without his/her consent) is not desirable in the internet world.

Will my message be completely deleted. If yes, when?

(Note: There is a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123205/156411). But it was closed for being too localized. Please don't close this one too, because this question had to be asked.)

Comment: the answer I deleted on Sep 16 '11 is still there ([10K+ only link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7056456/839601)) - you can safely assume it is expected to be there forever

Comment: @hkBattousai - If you want the answer even less visible (to the 0.1% with enough rep), you can edit your answer and replace it with  "Never mind. I misunderstood the question.". *Very* few will care enough to look up the original post in the edit history.

Answer (score 13):

Never.

> Even though only myself and high reputed trusted users can see it, this situation (keeping deleted user entries without his/her consent) is not desirable in the internet world.

Actually, many "delete" buttons on the Net are only soft deletions. Fact is, they don't want you removing valuable content at whim.

> (keeping deleted user entries without his/her consent

You gave consent by accepting the [ToS](https://stackexchange.com/legal):

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license. You grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content and to allow others to do so in any medium now known or hereinafter developed (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services, **even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by You**. Subscriber warrants, represents and agrees Subscriber has the right to grant Stack Exchange and the Network the rights set forth above. Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber Content that (a) infringes, violates or otherwise interferes with any copyright or trademark of another party, (b) reveals any trade secret, unless Subscriber owns the trade secret or has the owner’s permission to post it, (c) infringes any intellectual property right of another or the privacy or publicity rights of another, (d) is libelous, defamatory, abusive, threatening, harassing, hateful, offensive or otherwise violates any law or right of any third party, (e) contains a virus, trojan horse, worm, time bomb or other computer programming routine or engine that is intended to damage, detrimentally interfere with, surreptitiously intercept or expropriate any system, data or information, or (f) remains posted after Subscriber has been notified that such Subscriber Content violates any of sections (a) to (e) of this sentence. Stack Exchange reserves the right to remove any Subscriber Content from the Network, **re-post to the Network any Subscriber Content removed by any Subscriber or former Subscriber**, suspend or terminate Subscriber’s right to use the Services at any time, or pursue any other remedy or relief available to Stack Exchange and/or the Network under equity or law, for any reason (including, but not limited to, upon receipt of claims or allegations from third parties or authorities relating to such Subscriber Content or if Stack Exchange is concerned that Subscriber may have breached the immediately preceding sentence), or for no reason at all.

(emphasis mine)

Paraphrased with legalese removed:

> Whatever you write on SE is practically owned by SE. It is still attributed to you, and is protected by the [CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/) license. Removing content does not change this, SE still has all rights over it, and can do whatever it wants with it.

Basically, the "delete" button is "please hide this from the masses".

If you have placed sensitive information in the post, you can always ask a dev to get it removed. Email `team@stackexchange.com`. Or flag the post for mod attention, asking for it to be removed.

Comment: FYI, using a mod flag for the sensitive information situation is also an option (obviously, mentioning that a revision needs removing, so they can get a dev / employee).  I have no clue which one's quicker, though.

Comment: @jadarnel27: Hmm, I forgot about flagging. Yeah, I guess it's faster--mods on most sites except SO deal with flags pretty quickly. They then ping one of the <s>six</s> five community mods (atleast one of them is online in TL), and they get it done. I dunno if the community mods have the power to do it (they might just ping a dev), but it's pretty fast.

Answer (score 7):

"... without his/her consent"

you gave consent actually, go read the terms of agreement that YOU already agreed if you don't belive me